# glsl layout with glvertexattribpointer issues

Tags: layout, glsl, vbo

So I have a working program that displays a terrain mesh generated from a height map. I want to use the layout qualifier to declare the vertex attributes now, but I am having issues. When I just use the built in gl_Normal for my normals, everything works fine. When I use a normal declared with the layout qualifier, it does not work. The vertices display just fine regardless. I'm not sure as to what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is the generation of the buffers:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &TerrainPVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TerrainPVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Terrains[IID].Points.size() * sizeof(vec3f), &Terrains[IID].Points[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);



glGenBuffers(1, &TerrainNVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, TerrainNVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Terrains[IID].Normals.size() * sizeof(vec3f), &Terrains[IID].Normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

Then down in my rendering function:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, TerrainIVBO);
glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 3);
glDrawElements(GL_PATCHES, Terrains[IID].Index.size(),  GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

If I do not use The VertexAttribArray/Pointer, and I use glVertexPointer/glNormalPointer in the drawing function (with gl_Normal/gl_Vertex in the shader), everything works fine.

This is the shader, if that helps at all:

```
#version 420


uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;

layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;


out gl_PerVertex{
vec4 gl_Position;
};

out vec3 normalTCS;


void main()
{    
gl_Position = vertex;
normalTCS = NormalMatrix * normal;
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here, but I find this process a bit confusing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your isse is, but using `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` for your normals is not going to work. The `glVertexAttribPointer()` calls will always reference the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, so you set up your noramls to be identical to your positions.

However, `glNormalPointer()` works the same way, so it is toally unclear to me how this could have worked before.

Comment: I KNEW I was doing something stupid. My normals don't appear to be the same as they were before, but they do seem to be accurate. The issue of it being element_array was only created when I converted to this method. That's why it worked before. Cheers!